# How to add a song to the beginning of a jPlayer playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I'm making a site that uses jPlayer playlist. I need to use a function that adds a song to the beginning of the playlist (or an index), but the only add function that I see adds songs to the end of the playlist.

According to their [site](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/), their add function is

```
add(media:Object, [playNow:Boolean]) : Void
Add a media item to the end of the playlist. Optional playNow param to start it playing after adding it.
```

I don't see any support for adding to the beginning of the playlist. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. :)  You can grab a copy of the current playlist, add a new playlist item to the start of the list and reset the playlist again:

```
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({...});
var tempPlaylistItems = myPlaylist.playlist;
myPlaylist.setPlaylist(tempPlaylistItems.unshift({title: "blah", artist: "blah", mp3: "blah", oga: "blah", poster: "blah"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your media at the end and play it the first with this method: myPlaylist.play(-1);

```
    $("#add-new-song").click(function() {
    myPlaylist.add({
        title:"Hidden",
        artist:"Miaow",
        free: true,
        mp3:"g/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
        oga:"/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg",
        poster: "/audio/poster/Miaow_640x360.png"
    });
    myPlaylist.play(-1);
});
```